# If (is_page_template()) not working in header.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 3 separate header options, all with a banner image:
1. Homepage
2. Sponsor Template
3. All other pages.

I have placed the below code in the header. The homepage and all other pages are working as expected, but I can't seem to make the Sponsor template work (the class="sponsor-title" is not appearing).

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( is_front_page()): ?>
    <span class="home"><h1><?php echo event_title(); ?></h1></span>
    <span class="tag-line"><?php the_field('tag_line'); ?></span>
    <span class="date"><?php the_field('date_time_header'); ?></span>
    <?php 
        $ticket = get_field('ticket_url');
        if ( $ticket ): 
            $ticket_url = $ticket['url'];
            $ticket_title = $ticket['title'];
        ?>
        <a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url($ticket_url); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($ticket_title); ?></a>
<?php if (!is_page_template('page-templates/all-sponsor-template.php')); ?>
    <span class="sponsor-title"><h1><?php echo event_title(); ?></h1></span>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <span class="page-title"><h1><?php the_field('page_header'); ?></h1></span>
    <span class="sub-header"><?php the_field('sub_header'); ?></span>
<?php endif;?>
```

What have I done wrong? I want to ensure that when the template or page is chosen that the correct styling appears, as it is very different from the other pages.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/253820/how-to-use-if-is-page-template

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php if (!is_page_template('page-templates/all-sponsor-template.php')); ?>
    // Stuff
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here you are checking if the page template is NOT `page-templates/all-sponsor-template.php`, and if it isn't - then you show the sponsor title...

I might be confused, but shouldn't it be like this?

```php
<?php if (is_page_template('page-templates/all-sponsor-template.php')); ?>
    // Stuff
<?php endif; ?>
```

I.e. swapping the if condition so that the sponsor title shows if the page template IS the mentioned file.

**Edit:**
The if statement that checks if the sponsor page template is being used, is inside the if statement that checks if the current page is the home page.

If you move the template check one level up, it should do the trick:

```php
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( is_front_page()): ?>
    <span class="home"><h1><?php echo event_title(); ?></h1></span>
    <span class="tag-line"><?php the_field('tag_line'); ?></span>
    <span class="date"><?php the_field('date_time_header'); ?></span>

    <?php 
    $ticket = get_field('ticket_url');
    if ( $ticket ): 
    $ticket_url = $ticket['url'];
    $ticket_title = $ticket['title'];
    ?>
    <a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url($ticket_url); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($ticket_title); ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (is_page_template('page-templates/all-sponsor-template.php')); ?>
    <span class="sponsor-title"><h1><?php echo event_title(); ?></h1></span>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php else: ?>
    <span class="page-title"><h1><?php the_field('page_header'); ?></h1></span>
    <span class="sub-header"><?php the_field('sub_header'); ?></span>
<?php endif;?>
```

This way it will check if the sponsor template is being used on all pages and not only when on the home page.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I'm not strong on PHP. It's appearing on the homepage under the button, but not on the template page.

Comment: Ok. I think it is because you're checking for `is_page_template()` inside your `is_front_page()` check - so it will never be true unless on the home page. I updated my answer with another suggestion.

Comment: I changed the semi-colon to a colon on is_page_template line to stop a site error and added in the extra endif. It has stopped appearing on the front page, but it still showing the else code on all-sponsor-template.php

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the syntax of your `if` statement. Try this instead:

```
<?php if (!is_page_template('page-templates/all-sponsor-template.php')) { ?>
<span class="sponsor-title"><h1><?php echo event_title(); ?></h1></span>
<?php } else { ?>
<span class="page-title"><h1><?php the_field('page_header'); ?></h1></span>
<span class="sub-header"><?php the_field('sub_header'); ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

I always use the `{..}` brackets, as it's easier to follow and understand the logic of the code. However, to rewrite your code using the correct structure of the `if` statement you've attempted, it would look like this:

```
<?php if (!is_page_template('page-templates/all-sponsor-template.php')): ?>
<span class="sponsor-title"><h1><?php echo event_title(); ?></h1></span>
<?php else: ?>
<span class="page-title"><h1><?php the_field('page_header'); ?></h1></span>
<span class="sub-header"><?php the_field('sub_header'); ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And, of course, the exclamation mark here:

```
if (!is_page_template('page-templates/all-sponsor-template.php'))
```

means "If NOT page template all-sponsor-template.php" so remove it if you are checking for TRUE.

Finally, keep in mind that due to certain global variables being overwritten during The Loop, `is_page_template()` will not work in The Loop. However, if this code is in your `header.php`, then you should be fine.

Comment: thanks. When I try that I get "The site is experiencing technical difficulties." Not sure what I'm doing wrong. The code works until <?php if (!is_page_template('page-templates/all-sponsor-template.php')): ?>
<span class="sponsor-title"><h1><?php echo event_title(); ?></h1></span>. Thanks for the tip about the !

Comment: The "technical difficulties" error means a fatal PHP error. Did you try the first block of code with the `if {..} else {..}` instead? I find that's easier to use and understand...

Comment: The only thing it can be are one of the other functions are undefined. Turn on the debug log (in wp-config.php: `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );`), refresh the page, then check wp-content/debug.log - it should tell more about the error you're experiencing.

Comment: Thanks, I followed your instructions, changed the semi-colon to a colon on is_page_template line and added in the extra endif. It has stopped appearing on the front page, but it still showing the else code on all-sponsor-template.php.

Comment: What did the debug log say? Also, forget using the colons and endifs - just use the curly brackets for simplicity. Like I said, I've tested that structure and it works 100%, so my guess is one of those functions isn't defined where your code is running. That's why we need the debug log information. It will tell you if one of the functions is not known at runtime.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF) in /home/ftpuser/www/wp-content/themes/event-child/header.php on line 151. The last line is a comment and before that is the breadcrumb code and a few divs

Comment: That sounds like there's some other `if..else` statement that's not closed. Can you drop a copy of your header.php file into pastebin.com and I'll take a look.

Comment: thank you!!! https://pastebin.com/gx18Zgzg this is a child theme, so I have left the code that was in there and then added my own as I didn't want to stuff anything up :)

Comment: The `if` statement on line 127 `if ( $ticket ):` doesn't appear to have a closing `endif;` statement.

Comment: Even with the `endif;` statement on line 132, I still get an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF) in /home/ftpuser/www/wp-content/themes/event-child/header.php on line 159

Comment: Also looks like line 120 `<?php if ( is_front_page()): ?>` isn't being closed either? I think that's the last one... fingers crossed!

Comment: SO close. It is working, but the code under the `else` statement is appearing on the homepage. I REALLY appreciate your time and effort in this :)